How can I access query parameters of the callback url in next-auth?
I'm building a nextjs (app router) web application and I'm using NextAuth.js for authentication. I want my users to be able to login using Todoist, so I'm using the Todoist provider. As far as I understand one should use a callback similar to <domain>/api/auth/callback/<provider>. When the user authorises my app, then todoist redirects the user to the redirect URL. However, the redirect request will come with two query parameters (code, state) that will be needed to get an access token (to get access to the user's data). NextAuth.js automatically redirects me to the home page ("/") if authorisation is successful.
How do I access these query parameters? Below is my code.
//auth.config.ts
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import TodoistProvider from "next-auth/providers/todoist";

export const authConfig: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    TodoistProvider({
      clientId: process.env.TODOIST_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.TODOIST_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
};

//app/api/auth[...nextauth]/route.ts
import { authConfig } from "@/lib/auth.config";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

const handler = NextAuth(authConfig);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

I've tried creating a route based on my callback URL and customising the authConfig by adding callbacks.
